# Android listview, show user end of list and then auto scroll to the top

Tags: android, listview, arraylist, scroll, android-arrayadapter

I have Listviews within layouts and I want the user to know that there are more cells to see, and to scroll. The listviews do not have a scrollbar visible by default.

One suggestion I got was to start displaying the list from the end of it and then auto scroll upwards to the top. This would show the user that there is something to scroll.

How would this be done on Android?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use the functions which are part of the ListView class:

```
smoothScrollByOffset(int offset);
```

or

```
smoothScrollToPosition(int position);
```

---

Or if you want to scroll one by one you could use functions like:

```
private void scrollToNext() {
int currentPosition = getListView().getFirstVisiblePosition();
if (currentPosition == getListView().getCount() - 1)
    return;
getListView().setSelection(currentPosition + 1);
getListView().clearFocus();
}

private void scrollToPrevious() {
int currentPosition = getListView().getFirstVisiblePosition();
if (currentPosition == 0)
    return;
getListView().setSelection(currentPosition - 1);
getListView().clearFocus();
}
```